# How to design this bass drum?

Tags: music, electronic-music, drum, kick

Hello everybody my first Question here, so please tell me if I do something wrong.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93ASUImTedo

I love the Kickdrum of Disclosure, which and tried to replicate it, but failed horribly.
I think they use the same Bassdrum in their track white noise too.

I know that they use Drum Machines (analogue imo) and samples.

My first idea was to use a 808 Kick sample with a pitch envelope of ca. 12 semitones in the first 200 ms or so. I played around with the values and equed out some knocking in the low mids and boosted the punchy 80 hz area. After that i used some Opto type compressor to bring out the initial punch a bit more. I tried to soften the initial click of the 808 by using a 10-20 ms amp envelope. The reason why i did this, is because their drums are deep and have a really nice pitch shift form in the frequency analyzer.

The problem is => my attempts always lead to a way to high aggressive punch/attack compared to Disclosures kicks. I used all sort of basic samples, saturated, clean eq-ed 808s 909s etc. (a lot of urban coockbook 2)

I dont think they use vengeance drums because their sound is so warm and feels "uncompressed", "breathing" and soft

Can you please please help me how to get this sound, or tell me what drum machine they use for that kick.

Thanks and regards.
Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "to design" you mean "to create", then..

It sounds very much of a Roland 909 kick, with possible alterations (e.g. compression). It's clearly compressed but mixed low so that it doesn't sound big.

It's not a surprise, but rather a known fact that many kick sounds in electronic music are based on either the Roland 808 (= very pure sine-ish tone) or 909 kick (= the classic "house" kick with a nice snap/attack), which may have been pitched, enveloped and layered with duplicates or other samples.

Comment: I am not sure with the 909 since it sounds to deep for a 909 (i cant hear the triangle waveform), maybe it is filtered?

Comment: Well it's obviously altered in some way, as all kicks are, but I think it's reasonably close to a 909 to suggest that it could work as the base sample. And as it's a common fact that the 808/909 kick is most often used as the base sample. You may find an even closer sample from some sample pack, but constructing a kick sound is quite fun.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then I'd try to get something reminiscent from a monophonic subtractive synthesizer and use that as the base.

Comment: Yeah i want to learn to create those, since its the founddation of edm music and i think its un kreative if you just take a vengeance sample drop it in the daw. I will try to envelope some 909 samples and automate a filter on it to bring out the warmth. thx

Comment: Ok man thx i think its an 909 i just knew the standard 909 sound but the machine itself has some nice variations that song like the one im searching, found a grat tape saturated pack of those, which i realy enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

certainly 909ish.  the rest of the drums are certainly 909/808 inspired and Disclosure's production in general is highly influenced by the classic 90s house/2-step sound.

the kick and snare sound tape saturated to me. also sounds like the whole track is 2bussed through an SSL Comp.

Comment: Yeah i am playing around with 909s from goldbaby right now, but i still have troubles to get that soft/deep but still punchy sound. any ideas how to process the raw samples? normaly i laver vynil noise + a hi hat ontop of the kick, remove mud at 300- 500 hz check for resonation bouncy frequenzys at 100 hz and then run them trough a nice punchy compressor (h-comp) to get rid of boomy tails. but i just ant get close enough and that is driving me crazy .D

Comment: the mastering of the track as a whole is a large part of the sound of the sounds. :)   like you mentioned, they are probably using a 909 clone type drum machine like a Jomox xox09.  I personally shorten boomy tails by trimming/fading the waveform rather than compression. When i get my kick the way i like it, i try not to treat it much more so not to ruin it. This is especially true in mastering. You can easily ruin the sound and feel of what you created by heavy compression in mastering.


Answer (score 0):

It's a 5 minute job in Rob Papen's Punch. Try it.

Comment: Give it a try thx